# I want to get all records according to per day

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want to get all records according to per day Group by user id and
 count L point and R point and M point, according to user id and get
 record according to per day

```
     CREATE TABLE [dbo].[payoutPoints](
            [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
            [userid] [int] NOT NULL,
            [payoutBatchId] [int] NOT NULL,
            [points] [int] NOT NULL,
            [pointPosition] [char](1) NOT NULL,
            [forUserId] [int] NOT NULL,
            [insertDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
         CONSTRAINT [PK_payoutPoints] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
        (
            [id] ASC
        )WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
        ) ON [PRIMARY]
        GO
        SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
        GO
        SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[payoutPoints] ON
        INSERT [dbo].[payoutPoints] ([id], [userid], [payoutBatchId], [points], [pointPosition], [forUserId], [insertDate]) VALUES (256, 4, 5, 1, N'R', 149, CAST(0x0000A5140128A180 AS DateTime))
        INSERT [dbo].[payoutPoints] ([id], [userid], [payoutBatchId], [points], [pointPosition], [forUserId], [insertDate]) VALUES (299, 4, 5, 1, N'L', 182, CAST(0x0000A51700B91CCA AS DateTime))
        INSERT [dbo].[payoutPoints] ([id], [userid], [payoutBatchId], [points], [pointPosition], [forUserId], [insertDate]) VALUES (300, 149, 5, 1, N'L', 183, CAST(0x0000A51700BC2CA9 AS DateTime))
        INSERT [dbo].[payoutPoints] ([id], [userid], [payoutBatchId], [points], [pointPosition], [forUserId], [insertDate]) VALUES (301, 4, 5, 1, N'R', 183, CAST(0x0000A51700BC2CA9 AS DateTime))
        INSERT [dbo].[payoutPoints] ([id], [userid], [payoutBatchId], [points], [pointPosition], [forUserId], [insertDate]) VALUES (302, 149, 5, 1, N'R', 184, CAST(0x0000A51700C0FD98 AS DateTime))
        INSERT [dbo].[payoutPoints] ([id], [userid], [payoutBatchId], [points], [pointPosition], [forUserId], [insertDate]) VALUES (303, 4, 5, 1, N'R', 184, CAST(0x0000A51700C0FD98 AS DateTime))
        INSERT [dbo].[payoutPoints] ([id], [userid], [payoutBatchId], [points], [pointPosition], [forUserId], [insertDate]) VALUES (304, 149, 5, 0, N'M', 185, CAST(0x0000A51700C1DFB4 AS DateTime))
        INSERT [dbo].[payoutPoints] ([id], [userid], [payoutBatchId], [points], [pointPosition], [forUserId], [insertDate]) VALUES (305, 4, 5, 0, N'R', 185, CAST(0x0000A51700C1DFB4 AS DateTime))
        INSERT [dbo].[payoutPoints] ([id], [userid], [payoutBatchId], [points], [pointPosition], [forUserId], [insertDate]) VALUES (306, 185, 5, 1, N'L', 186, CAST(0x0000A51700C29FAC AS DateTime))
        INSERT [dbo].[payoutPoints] ([id], [userid], [payoutBatchId], [points], [pointPosition], [forUserId], [insertDate]) VALUES (307, 149, 5, 1, N'M', 186, CAST(0x0000A51700C29FAC AS DateTime))
        INSERT [dbo].[payoutPoints] ([id], [userid], [payoutBatchId], [points], [pointPosition], [forUserId], [insertDate]) VALUES (308, 4, 5, 1, N'R', 186, CAST(0x0000A51700C29FAC AS DateTime))
        INSERT [dbo].[payoutPoints] ([id], [userid], [payoutBatchId], [points], [pointPosition], [forUserId], [insertDate]) VALUES (309, 185, 5, 1, N'R', 187, CAST(0x0000A51700C33073 AS DateTime))
        INSERT [dbo].[payoutPoints] ([id], [userid], [payoutBatchId], [points], [pointPosition], [forUserId], [insertDate]) VALUES (310, 149, 5, 1, N'M', 187, CAST(0x0000A51700C33073 AS DateTime))
        INSERT [dbo].[payoutPoints] ([id], [userid], [payoutBatchId], [points], [pointPosition], [forUserId], [insertDate]) VALUES (311, 4, 5, 1, N'R', 187, CAST(0x0000A51700C33073 AS DateTime))
        INSERT [dbo].[payoutPoints] ([id], [userid], [payoutBatchId], [points], [pointPosition], [forUserId], [insertDate]) VALUES (312, 182, 5, 1, N'L', 188, CAST(0x0000A51700C3BB78 AS DateTime))
        INSERT [dbo].[payoutPoints] ([id], [userid], [payoutBatchId], [points], [pointPosition], [forUserId], [insertDate]) VALUES (313, 4, 5, 1, N'L', 188, CAST(0x0000A51700C3BB78 AS DateTime))
        INSERT [dbo].[payoutPoints] ([id], [userid], [payoutBatchId], [points], [pointPosition], [forUserId], [insertDate]) VALUES (314, 188, 5, 0, N'L', 189, CAST(0x0000A51700CA44B9 AS DateTime))
        INSERT [dbo].[payoutPoints] ([id], [userid], [payoutBatchId], [points], [pointPosition], [forUserId], [insertDate]) VALUES (315, 182, 5, 0, N'L', 189, CAST(0x0000A51700CA44B9 AS DateTime))
        INSERT [dbo].[payoutPoints] ([id], [userid], [payoutBatchId], [points], [pointPosition], [forUserId], [insertDate]) VALUES (316, 4, 5, 0, N'L', 189, CAST(0x0000A51700CA44B9 AS DateTime))
        INSERT [dbo].[payoutPoints] ([id], [userid], [payoutBatchId], [points], [pointPosition], [forUserId], [insertDate]) VALUES (317, 189, 5, 0, N'L', 190, CAST(0x0000A51700CADF58 AS DateTime))
        INSERT [dbo].[payoutPoints] ([id], [userid], [payoutBatchId], [points], [pointPosition], [forUserId], [insertDate]) VALUES (318, 188, 5, 0, N'L', 190, CAST(0x0000A51700CADF58 AS DateTime))
        INSERT [dbo].[payoutPoints] ([id], [userid], [payoutBatchId], [points], [pointPosition], [forUserId], [insertDate]) VALUES (319, 182, 5, 0, N'L', 190, CAST(0x0000A51700CADF58 AS DateTime))
        INSERT [dbo].[payoutPoints] ([id], [userid], [payoutBatchId], [points], [pointPosition], [forUserId], [insertDate]) VALUES (320, 4, 5, 0, N'L', 190, CAST(0x0000A51700CADF58 AS DateTime))
        INSERT [dbo].[payoutPoints] ([id], [userid], [payoutBatchId], [points], [pointPosition], [forUserId], [insertDate]) VALUES (321, 187, 5, 1, N'L', 192, CAST(0x0000A517010F1535 AS DateTime))
        INSERT [dbo].[payoutPoints] ([id], [userid], [payoutBatchId], [points], [pointPosition], [forUserId], [insertDate]) VALUES (322, 185, 5, 1, N'R', 192, CAST(0x0000A517010F1547 AS DateTime))
        INSERT [dbo].[payoutPoints] ([id], [userid], [payoutBatchId], [points], [pointPosition], [forUserId], [insertDate]) VALUES (323, 149, 5, 1, N'M', 192, CAST(0x0000A517010F1547 AS DateTime))
        INSERT [dbo].[payoutPoints] ([id], [userid], [payoutBatchId], [points], [pointPosition], [forUserId], [insertDate]) VALUES (324, 4, 5, 1, N'R', 192, CAST(0x0000A517010F1547 AS DateTime))
        SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[payoutPoints] OFF


    GO
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO
    /*
    exec [test]
    @userId =4
    */

    alter PROC [dbo].[test]

      @userId integer

       AS
    BEGIN

      declare @totalLPoint as int;
      declare @totalRPoint as int;
      declare @totalMPoint as int;
      declare @MainIdPlacement as char;
      declare @ResultLpoint as int;
      declare @ResultRpoint as int;

        select @MainIdPlacement=mainidplacement from binaryUser where pId=@userId and MainIdPlacement!='0'     



        IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE #temp

         IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#result') IS NOT NULL
         DROP TABLE #result

         create table #result
          (
           date varchar(max),
           leftpoint int,
           rightpoint int
          ) 


        create table #temp
        (
        alldate date
         )
        insert into #temp (alldate) (select distinct(CONVERT(varchar(10),insertDate, 111)) as allDate  from payoutPoints )


        declare @date nvarchar(50)
        declare @RowNum int
        declare CustList cursor for
        select * from #temp
        OPEN CustList
        FETCH NEXT FROM CustList 
        INTO @date
        set @RowNum = 0 
        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN     

         DECLARE @start_date as datetime
         DECLARE @end_date as datetime     
         set @start_date=  cast(convert(varchar(30), @date, 110) as datetime)     
         set @end_date=  CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @date, 110) + ' 23:59:59' AS DATETIME)  


         --set condition

        SELECT @totalMPoint=SUM(points)  FROM payoutPoints   
        WHERE payoutPoints.userid = @userId AND payoutPoints.pointPosition ='M' and payoutPoints.insertDate between @start_date
        and @end_date
        GROUP BY pointPosition    

        SELECT @totalLPoint= SUM(points)  FROM payoutPoints   
        WHERE payoutPoints.userid = @userId AND payoutPoints.pointPosition ='L' 

         and
        payoutPoints.insertDate between @start_date
        and @end_date
        GROUP BY pointPosition 

        SELECT @totalRPoint= SUM(points)  FROM payoutPoints   
        WHERE payoutPoints.userid = @userId AND payoutPoints.pointPosition ='R'     
         and
        payoutPoints.insertDate between @start_date
        and @end_date

        GROUP BY pointPosition 

        --end

        --set condition to sum c leg 

            if(@MainIdPlacement='R')
           begin
        set @ResultRpoint=(@totalMPoint +@totalRPoint)

           end
        else
            begin
         set @ResultRpoint=@totalRPoint        

       end         

            if(@MainIdPlacement='L')
           begin
        set @ResultLpoint=(@totalMPoint +@totalLPoint)

           end
        else
            begin
         set @ResultLpoint=@totalLPoint        

       end   
          --end     



              insert into #result values(@date,@ResultLpoint,@ResultRpoint)

          FETCH NEXT FROM CustList 
            INTO @date

        END
        CLOSE CustList
        DEALLOCATE CustList

       select * from #result



     --get left and right point


    end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This definitely doesn't need a `CURSOR`.

You can do this for one person with just one statement:

```
SELECT
  CAST(pp.insertDate AS DATE) date,
  SUM(CASE WHEN pp.pointPosition = 'L' THEN pp.points END) AS leftpoint,
  SUM(CASE WHEN pp.pointPosition = 'R' THEN pp.points END) AS rightpoint
FROM dbo.payoutPoints AS pp
WHERE pp.userid = 4
GROUP BY CAST(pp.insertDate AS DATE);
```

Or build it into a procedure that takes the UserID:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE #GetPointsForUser
  @UserID INT
AS
  SELECT
    CAST(pp.insertDate AS DATE) date,
    SUM(CASE WHEN pp.pointPosition = 'L' THEN pp.points END) AS leftpoint,
    SUM(CASE WHEN pp.pointPosition = 'R' THEN pp.points END) AS rightpoint,
    SUM(CASE WHEN pp.pointPosition = 'M' THEN pp.points END) AS mpoint
  FROM dbo.payoutPoints AS pp
  WHERE pp.userid = @userId
  GROUP BY CAST(pp.insertDate AS DATE);
GO


EXEC #GetPointsForUser @UserID = 4;
```

To take into account `MainIdPlacement` in the `binaryUser` table, you could use the results returned by the above SELECT statement as a derived table and add `mpoint` to `leftpoint` or `rightpoint` conditionally based on the value of `MainIdPlacement`, like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE #GetPointsForUser
  @UserID INT
AS
  SELECT
    p.date,
    p.leftpoint  + ISNULL(CASE u.MainIdPlacement WHEN 'L' THEN p.mpoint, 0) AS leftpoint,
    p.rightpoint + ISNULL(CASE u.MainIdPlacement WHEN 'R' THEN p.mpoint, 0) AS rightpoint
  FROM
    (
      SELECT
        CAST(pp.insertDate AS DATE) date,
        SUM(CASE WHEN pp.pointPosition = 'L' THEN pp.points END) AS leftpoint,
        SUM(CASE WHEN pp.pointPosition = 'R' THEN pp.points END) AS rightpoint,
        SUM(CASE WHEN pp.pointPosition = 'M' THEN pp.points END) AS mpoint
      FROM dbo.payoutPoints AS pp
      WHERE pp.userid = @userId
      GROUP BY CAST(pp.insertDate AS DATE)
    ) AS p
    LEFT JOIN binaryUser AS u ON u.pId = @userId
      AND u.MainIdPlacement <> '0'  -- this may be unnecessary
  ;
GO
```

If `pId` is the primary key of `binaryUser`, the `u.MainIdPlacement <> '0'` predicate is probably unnecessary, as stated in the comment.

Comment: its not working  Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure #GetPointsForUser, Line 6
Incorrect syntax near ','.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure #GetPointsForUser, Line 18
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.